# Styling the default scrollbar in Vue

Tags: css, vue.js, web, webkit

I'm attempting to style the thumb of the default scrollbar in vue (black background so no way of seeing the default currently) I've tried all of the following and there's been no difference

```
 main::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 2px;
  /* background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5); */
  background-color: #00FF01;
  color: #00FF01;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   border-radius: 2px;
  /* background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5); */
  background-color: #00FF01;
  color: #00FF01;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   border-radius: 2px;
  /* background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5); */
  background-color: #00FF01;
  color: #00FF01;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

Is the implementation of webkit different?

Comment: Hey, give it a read- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar

Comment: @NehaSoni already did, it isn't helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all of the `::webkit-scrollbar-*` pseudo-elements can only work if at least 1 CSS attribute is defined in the "entire scrollbar" pseudo-element `::webkit-scrollbar`

Try them together:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   border-radius: 2px;
  /* background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5); */
  background-color: #00FF01;
  color: #00FF01;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```